# Google Sites words in navigation bar is "one-line-only". How to make it multi-line?

Tags: google-classic-sites

I use **horizontal navigation bar** in Google sites, however the problem is that the words in the horizontal navigation bar is "single-lined".

I am allowed to change the text in the navigation bar, but no matter how I try, I couldn't get the behavior to be "multi-lined".

For example, I want my navigation bar to look like this:

```
Helloooooooooo | Helloooooooooo | Helloooooooooo
Worldddddddddd | Worlddddddddd2 | Worlddddddddd3
```

Right now, it is all in one line:

```
Helloooooooooo Worldddddddddd | Helloooooooooo Worlddddddddd2 | Helloooooooooo Worlddddddddd3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished by setting `max-width` or `width` property in CSS on the enclosing element (usually, navigation links are enclosed in `<li>`). However, Google Sites doesn't give access to the template's CSS so there's no way to do multi-line navigation links.

Comment: Is there a hack we can use to modify the CSS?

Comment: No global hack (only local view). It's permanently disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by a global hack?

Comment: Meaning something that would change it for all visitors. You can change it for yourself locally.

Comment: how would i do a *local view* hack?

Comment: You open your browser's developer tools, you find the element that contains your navigation, and you change its style. This is utterly useless because you must be looking at the same view as your visitors when designing a site.

Comment: ic, this is not what I wanted then.

Comment: Well, there's no other way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a link to the site in question? Are you using the 'navigation' widget in the Site Layout or your own text nav?

If it's your own text nav you can set up a table then copy paste the nav onto each page, it's very easy to get rid of the lines on Google Sites tables.

If it's the nav widget consider make sub navigation on all of your main category pages or doing drop down menus off of the Nav widget itself.

If it's style you're going for you can always make an image based navigation and image map the click points to different URL's.